# How to display contents centrally in xml UI?

Tags: android-layout

I have problem while doing landscape mode of 3.7 inch mobile.
i wrote following xml file and its displaying correct horizontally & vertically center in 10 inch tablet.
but when run in 3.7 inch(landscape mode) it doesnt display Login title but directly displays from UserId.
I want to display from top if running in 3.7 inch mobile(landscape mode).
if anybody can try to solve this problem , plz try it.
Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:gravity="center" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            >
                        </ImageView>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtLoginTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Login"
                            android:textColor="#005595"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="280dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtUserId"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:text=" User ID"
                            android:textColor="#005595"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edUserId"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:singleLine="true" >
                        </EditText>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="280dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text=" Password"
                            android:textColor="#005595"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edPassword"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                            android:password="true"
                            android:singleLine="true" >
                        </EditText>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="280dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtCompany"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:text=" Company"
                            android:textColor="#005595"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/edCompany"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:imeOptions="actionSend|actionDone|actionGo"
                            android:singleLine="true" >
                        </EditText>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnForgotPassword"
                            android:layout_width="205dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:text="Forgot Password ?"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                            android:layout_width="99dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:text="Login"
                            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```